# Javascript Unsorting Array Issue

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Whenever I try to set the array to empty and put the copy array in it only works two times before wrecking the code.I am trying to revert back to the original array. The two problem sports are commented in the code "THE PROBLEM" if you want to take a look.The '.one' and '.two' are labeled in the picture of the table if it helps any.Thanks in advance!

```js
var name;
var age;
var sex;
var person;
var flagOne;
var flagTwo;
var flagThree;
var array = [];
var holder = [];
var rowIndex;

createTable();

/* Modal Scripts */

$('.left').click(function(){

    $('#name').css('background-color','white');
    $('#age').css('background-color','white');
    $('#sex').css('background-color','white');

    name = $("#name").val('');
    age = $("#age").val('');
    sex = $("#sex").val('');

    $('.form-row:first-child').css('border','0');
    $('.form-row:nth-child(2)').css('border','0');
    $('.form-row:nth-child(3)').css('border','0');

    if($('td>a.delete').css('opacity') == 1){
        $('.modal-wrapper').css('display','none');
    }

    else  {
    $('.modal-wrapper').css('display','block');
    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity:1,
        marginTop:'-117px'
    },500);
}
});

$('.fa-times').click(function(){
    $('.modal-wrapper').css('display','none');

    name = $("#name").val('');
    age = $("#age").val('');
    sex = $("#sex").val('');

    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity:0,
        marginTop:'-250px'
    });
});

$('.modal-background').click(function(){
    $('.modal-wrapper').css('display','none');

    name = $("#name").val('');
    age = $("#age").val('');
    sex = $("#sex").val('');

    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity:0,
        marginTop:'-250px'
    });
});

/* Validation */

$('#button').click(function(){

    flagOne = false;
    flagTwo = false;
    flagThree = false;

    name = $("#name").val();
    age = $("#age").val();
    sex = $("#sex").val();

    if(name.match(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s[a-zA-z]{2,15})/)){
        flagOne = true;
    }
    else {
            flagOne = false;
    }

    if (age < 0 || age > 130 || isNaN(age) || age == '') {
            flagTwo = false;
    }
    else {
        flagTwo = true;
    }

        if (sex == "male" || sex == "Male" || sex == "female" || sex == "Female"){
            flagThree = true;
        }
        else {
            flagThree = false;
        }

        if(flagOne === false || flagTwo === false || flagThree === false){

            if(flagOne === false){
                $('#name').css('background-color','#FF7F7F');
            }
            else {
                $('#name').css('background-color','white');
            }

            if(flagTwo === false){
                $('#age').css('background-color','#FF7F7F');
            }
            else {
                $('#age').css('background-color','white');
            }

            if(flagThree === false){
                $('#sex').css('background-color','#FF7F7F');
            }
            else {
                $('#sex').css('background-color','white');
            }
        }

        else if(flagOne === true && flagTwo === true && flagThree === true) {
            $('.modal-wrapper').css('display','none');
            $('.modal').animate({
                    opacity:0,
                    marginTop:'-250px'
                });

            storeObject();
        }
});

/* Delete Button */

$('.right').click(function(){

    if($('td>a.delete').css('opacity') == 1){
        $('td>a.delete').css('opacity','0');
    }
    else if($('td>a.delete').css('opacity') == 0){
        $('td>a.delete').css('opacity','1');
    }
});

$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
    rowIndex = $('tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
    array.splice((rowIndex-1),1);
    testArray();
    $('td>a.delete').css('opacity','1');
});

/* Name Sort */

$(document).on('click','.one',function(){

    if($('.one').hasClass('rotate')){
      $('.one').removeClass('rotate');

        array = holder.splice(0);

        testArray();
    }
    else{

    $('.one').addClass('rotate');
    $('.two').removeClass('rotate');

    array.sort(compareNames);

    testArray();
    $('.one').addClass('rotate');
}
});

function compareNames(a,b) {
    if (a.name < b.name){
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/* Age Sort */

$(document).on('click','.two',function(){

        if($('.two').hasClass('rotate')){
            $('.two').removeClass('rotate');

            array = holder.splice(0);

            testArray();
        }
        else{

        $('.two').addClass('rotate');
        $('.one').removeClass('rotate');

        array.sort(compareNumbers);

        testArray();
        $('.two').addClass('rotate');
    }
});

function compareNumbers(a,b) {
    return a.age - b.age;
}

/* Array Creation */

function storeObject() {

function Person(name,age,sex){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.sex=sex;
}

person = new Person(name,age,sex);
array.push(person);
holder.push(person);

testArray();
}

/* Test Array */

function testArray() {
    if(array.length == 8){
        createTable();
        alert('Table Limit Reached!');
    }
    else if (array.length > 8){
        array.pop();
        alert('Too Many Rows!');
    }
    else {
        createTable();
    }
}

/* Table Creation */

function createTable() {
    var table = "<table><tr><td>Name<span class='special one'>▲</span></td><td>Age<span class='special two'>▲</span></td><td>Sex</td></tr>";
  for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++){
        if (array.length > 0){
    table += "<tr><td>" + array[i].name + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + array[i].age + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + array[i].sex + "<a class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></tr>";
    }
  }
  table += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("tablePrint").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: I do believe your issue is that your `.two` element is created dynamically _after_ the events have been attached. Try changing the first part to `$(document).on('click','.two',function(){...});` and let me know if that gets your desired results.

Comment: Wow! It works now. is there a way to undo the sort? @Jhecht

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean 'undo'? Like if I have the original order of say `1,5,4,2` -> sort -> `1,2,4,5` is there a way, given the result of the sort, to get the original order of `1,5,4,2`?

Comment: As there is no particular pattern for the original order of array, we can't undo it like that , but instead, you can keep a copy of the original array before sorting it and revert to it when you want to undo.

Comment: @suzo I have another problem with the code if you could help ( I update the code aswell).Whenever I try to set the array to empty and put the copy array in it only works two times before wrecking the code.I am trying to revert back to the original array. The two problem sports are commented in the code "THE PROBLEM" if you want to take a look.Thanks in advance!

Comment: `array`, `holder`, and `testArray` are undefined and you have not included the example HTML necessary for this to work. As such, there is no [mcve], which is required for debugging style questions.

Comment: Well... now it's just a code dump. That isn't a [mcve] either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making a copy of array by assigning it to a new variable. If you want to copy an array you should try `array.slice(0)`, that should create new instance of this array.

By doing:

```
array = [];
array = holder;
```

You are making variable `array` reference the `holder` variable. In second run, when the variable `array` is already reference to `holder` variable, you are making it both empty by calling `array = []`. That's why your code is stopping to work after 2nd run.

Suggested solution:

```
var array = holder.slice(0);
```

Comment: the second time either '.two' or '.one' is clicked , it deletes all the rows except for the Name,Age,Sex row now. any fix?

Comment: Can you update your question with fixed code? It would be easier to find what is the problem now.

Comment: I updated with the fix now

Comment: You are using splice function while it should be slice function (without "p" inside). Try with that!